# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at purple screen after update on March-2020

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, dell

My Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7567 was working fine before last month, and it received an update around March 20th, then it was stuck on a purple screen, before the splash screen. Recovery mode didn't work (stuck on loading initial ram disk). I can boot using live-cd ISO on USB drive, then after searching similar errors around, I tried applying the following fixes, with no luck at all:
-add dis_ucode_ldr to grub options;
-add nomodeset to grub options;
-downgrade intel-microcode to version 3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1 using chroot;
-remove quiet option but nothing more is displayed.

Then, I finally tried to reinstall using ubuntu 18.04.4 AMD-64 iso, then it worked again, until the first update. So, I'm stuck here. I have no idea what package is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the package. It was grub-efi-amd64-signed 1.93.16+2.02-2ubuntu8.15. Just downgraded to grub-efi-amd64-signed 1.93.15+2.02-2ubuntu8.14. Couldn't find the packages on the repositories, so I used the packages found at the ubuntu 18.04.4 iso.